# mockObserver.didPush can not using type any in didPush

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-test

Hi I'm trying to verify mockObserver to check push to other screen. But when didPush(any,any), it's show err from type any.

I'm using mockito: ^5.0.13

```
      (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
    await tester.tap(find.widgetWithText(TextButton, 'Join with us'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any));
  });
```